# Pretty print emailed json

Tags: python, django, json, heroku, sendgrid

I'm emailing a dict of json to myself from heroku in django using sendgrid. I'm trying to get it so instead of receiving a one line email:

```
{"dateAdded": “2013-09-13”, “description”: “blah”, "more": blah}
```

I receive it:

```
{
"dateAdded": “2013-09-13”, 
“description”: “blah”, 
"more": blah
}
```

Any ideas how I could accomplish this? I've tried the below code with no luck:

```
send_mail('Subject', json.dumps(doc), 'me@me.com', ['me@me.com'], fail_silently=False)
```

Comment: Does this work?: `json.dumps(doc, indent=True)`

Comment: @mariodev works a charm thanks! if you put it as an answer i'll accept it